# Converting org.joda.time to java.time

Tags: java, java-time

I am trying to replace org.joda.time with java.time in our Application.
Since, we were using org.joda.time packages, we have ISO8601 formatted period with org.joda.time.Period.

```
Period monthly = ISOPeriodFormat.standard().parsePeriod("P1M");
        Period yearly = ISOPeriodFormat.standard().parsePeriod("P1Y");
        Period weekly = ISOPeriodFormat.standard().parsePeriod("P1W");
        Period daily = ISOPeriodFormat.standard().parsePeriod("P1D");
        Period hour = ISOPeriodFormat.standard().parsePeriod("PT1H");
        Period minute = ISOPeriodFormat.standard().parsePeriod("PT1M");
```

Since the format like P1Y,P1M,P1W,P1D is been stored in our system, looking for the formatter for the same thing in java.time.

java.time.Duration supports, Hour, Minute and Day.

```
Duration dailyD = Duration.parse("P1D");
    Duration hourD = Duration.parse("PT1H");
    Duration minuteD = Duration.parse("PT5M");
```

But, dont see support for Week(P1W), Month(P1M), Year(P1Y) in java.time. Is there any other way to convert this to java.time.Period or java.time.Duration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **Duration** is a time-based amount of time.

A **Period** is a date-based amount of time.

For Duration you have tried correct.Please check if below examples work in your case

Period per1 = Period.ofDays(-4);    // P-4D

Period per1a = Period.ofDays(7);    // P7D

Period per2 = Period.ofWeeks(5);    // P5W

Period per3 = Period.ofMonths(-3);  // P-3M

Period per4 = Period.ofYears(2);    // P2Y